How to define a UUID identity column that satisfies both MySQL 8.4 and H2
I'm trying to implement a table that uses UUID instead of long as its identity column.
The long id implementation works perfectly, including end-to-end Spring MVC tests:
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name="myrecords")
public class myrecord {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

When I defined the table to use UUID instead of long as its identity column:
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name="myrecords")
public class myrecord {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "BINARY(16) DEFAULT (UUID_TO_BIN(UUID()))")
    private UUID id;

The application continues to work as intended, against the MySQL 8.4.3 database, but the tests that used to work against H2 in-memory database, now fail because H2 doesn't support columnDefinition = "BINARY(16) DEFAULT (UUID_TO_BIN(UUID()))".
In order to satisfy both MySQL and H2 (for production and test, respectively), my research revealed that I may need to resort to change the @GeneratedValue strategy to GenerationType.AUTO or use a custom ID generator (@GenericGenerator) for UUID.
However, by doing so I will lose the advantage of MySQL 8's optimization for UUID: https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/mysql-8-0-uuid-support/
What is the recommended approach for defining a UUID identity column such that it satisfies both MySQL 8.4 and H2?

The solution is to use exactly the same environment for both test and production! If your two environments are different, then you can never be sure that your tests catch all issues.

Use something like Testcontainers-java to use the same DBMS as your production environment instead of trying to shoehorn things so your tests work on two different DBMSes

Can this help? https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/spring-data-jpa-application-not-working-with-hibernate-and-h2/4970

You must be using Hibernate to create your tables - that isn't advisable in production. If your prod DB needs a special column definition that doesn't work on all databases (especially test databases), move it to a script that is only run in production when needed. Alternatively, you can override mappings using orm.xml so that you can have  slightly different options in test than you use in prod - I've used that as a way to get similar behavior behind the scenes without breaking the purpose of unit tests: ie define a different UUID identity generator in an orm.xml.

FYI, Flyway, Liquibase, etc.

@Chris Yes, I am using Hibernate to create my tables but not in production. What I described is still in DEV, specifically during test.

@Shadow Please post your comment as an answer and I will accept it. If you could cite (or provide a link to) an article that explains this principle, that would be super.

If hibernate is not creating tables in production- the column definition is irrelevant to prod. That is a hint only used for DDL, so you can remove it and use something appropriate for your test environment.
